# eclipse execute jar file run on linux machine

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, jar, noclassdeffounderror

My main code has two  class and main has two references

```
LookupService citylookup = new LookupService("D://GeoLiteCity.dat"...
FileReader fr =new FileReader("d:\\IP.txt");
```

I export them into an executable jar file and I get `D://testIP.jar` and `D://testIP_lib/reference libraries...jar`

I run `java -jar testIP.jar` and it works.

However, I revise my reference to linux machine path ex: `/home/admin/GeoLiteCity.dat`
and `/home/admin/IP.txt` and move `textIP.jar` and `testIP_lib` and `GeoLiteCity.dat IP.txt` to `/home/admin/`
I run `java -jar testIP.jar` again 
I get error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/maxmind/geoip/LookupService
    at testIP.CountryLookupTest.main(CountryLookupTest.java:18)
```

I check they are java 1.7..version
I don't know where I should set up ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a classpath difference between the two environments.  Check the `CLASSPATH` environment variable in both environments, and check the `Class-Path` entry in the `MANIFEST.MF` file in the jar.  I suspect that Eclipse built the jar with a Windows-based `Class-Path` entry in the Manifest file inside the jar.

Comment: You can examine the manifest file using any zip file viewer, such as Ark on Linux. It is inside the `META-INF` folder in the jar.

Comment: Good point - on Linux, you could use `unzip -p testIP.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` to dump the manifest file.

Comment: Yes, i need to check class-path check first, thank you robin for answer my question and improve my ugly page.

Comment: @louis It was a team effort: Robin formatted your question so I could read it, I answered it, and then Robin formatted my answer.  :)  Just out of curiosity, was it the `CLASSPATH` environment variable or the manifest entry that was incorrect?

Comment: I check again my class-path ,maybe  don't need to set up classpath on machine itself and place reference data and jar lib/ on the same location,it works.@matt forsythe sure it's team work :)

Answer (score 1):

If this is of any help.

> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html
>
> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/classpath.html

You would have to look how to use class path in the Linux environment.

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary, though, because the executable jar file should contain its own Class-Path (I'm guessing).

Comment: true, if the manifest file is update correctly and the dependency jars are enclosed in the jar itself

Comment: It is not necessary for the dependency jars to be inside the jar.

Comment: true it is not necessary, but still you would want them to be packaged along with to avoid the jars being on a separate file path. I mean user will have to take care of the dependency jars and make sure they are correctly placed. Beside I think its best to do a hit and try to know what settings will work out best.